# Why am I getting "UnboundLocalError" in my code?

Tags: python

I have revised the quotations to fix the syntax error. Now the error that I am receiving is this one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Programming Concepts\Labs\Chapter 11\Lab 8.py", line 78, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Programming Concepts\Labs\Chapter 11\Lab 8.py", line 18, in main
    totalPints = getTotal(pints)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Programming Concepts\Labs\Chapter 11\Lab 8.py", line 42, in getTotal
    totalPints += pints[counter]
  UnboundLocalError: local variable 'totalPints' referenced before assignment
```

Here is my code so far:

```
# Lab 8-3 Blood Drive

# The main function
def main():
    endProgram = 'no'
    print
    while endProgram == 'no':
        print
        # Declare variables
        pints = [0] * 7

        # Function calls
        pints = getPints(pints)
        totalPints = getTotal(pints)
        averagePints = getAverage(totalPints)
        highPints = getHigh(pints)
        lowPints = getLow(pints)
        displayInfo(averagePints, highPints, lowPints)

        endProgram = input('Do you want to end program? (Enter no or yes): ')
        while not (endProgram == 'yes' or endProgram == 'no'):
            print('Please enter a yes or no')
            endProgram = input('Do you want to end program? (Enter no or yes): ')

# The getPints function
def getPints(pints):
    counter = 0
    while counter < 7:
        numEntered = input('Enter pints collected: ')
        pints[counter] = int(numEntered)
        counter += 1
    return pints

# The getTotal function
def getTotal(pints):
    counter = 0
    while counter < 7:
        totalPints += pints[counter]
        counter += 1
    return totalPints

# The getAverage function
def getAverage(totalPints):
    averagePints = float(totalPints) / 7
    return averagePints

# The getHigh function
def getHigh(pints):
    highPints = pints[0]
    counter = 1
    while counter < 7:
        if pints[counter] > highPints:
            highPints = pints[counter]
        counter += 1
    return highPints

# The getLow function
def getLow():
    lowPints = pints[0]
    counter = 1
    while counter < 7:
        if pints[counter] < lowPints:\
           lowPints = pints[counter]
        counter += 1
    return lowPints

# The displayInfo function
def displayInfo(averagePints, highPints, lowPints):
    print('The average number of pints donated is ',averagePints)
    print('The highest pints donated is ', highPints)
    print('The lowest number of pints donated is ', lowPints)

# Calls main
main()
```

If anyone can copy and paste this code into their python and help troubleshoot it I would be greatful!

Comment: Are you writing your code using Microsoft Word or some other word processor?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change all your `‘` for quotes (`'` or `"`). Also you need to check your indentation inside your `getPints` function:

```
# The getPints function
def getPints(pints):
counter = 0
while counter < 7:
    numEntered = input(‘Enter pints collected: ‘)
    pints[counter] = int(numEntered)
    counter += 1
return pints
```

Indent one more level everything after the function definition just like you did in your `main` function:

```
# The getPints function
def getPints(pints):
    counter = 0
    while counter < 7:
        numEntered = input(‘Enter pints collected: ‘)
        pints[counter] = int(numEntered)
        counter += 1
    return pints
```

Comment: I have to add- the function getLow is not define with any parameters while his funtion calls
 lowPints = getLow(pints)
He should start using python built in functions, since iterating through a list is quite slow http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html, although it wont affect performance in this case

Comment: @user1462442 yes, but I think that might be a different question. I updated the title with actual problem the OP is facing

Answer (score 0):

"Variable referenced before assignment" just means that you're using a variable that doesn't exist yet.  In your code, the problem is this line:

```
totalPints += pints[counter]
```

which is  the first occurrence of totalPints.  Keep in mind that "+=" construction is exactly equivalent to

```
totalPints = totalPints + pints[counter]
```

and it's the right-hand occurrence that python is objecting to. To solve this, initialize your variable with

```
totalPints = 0
```

before you enter the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's an easy fix.
You just have to assign the variable before adding something to it.

```
totalPins = 0
```

or

```
totalPins = ""
```

before entering the loop should do the trick.